# Manually Trigger Jenkins/CloudBees CI Checks from GitHub: Combining Jenkinsfile with GitHub Actions or Workflows?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cicd, cloudbees

I've set up a Multibranch Pipeline job in Jenkins/CloudBees for a repository hosted on GitHub, and I've linked the repo to an internal Jenkins/CloudBees instance. Currently, whenever a pull request (PR) is raised, the continuous integration (CI) checks run automatically. However, I'd like to give users the ability to manually trigger these CI checks directly from GitHub.

I am not using GitHub Actions or any workflows; instead, I am solely relying on a Jenkinsfile to manage my pipeline.

Is there a way to achieve this without using GitHub Actions or workflows? Or, alternatively, is it possible to combine a Jenkinsfile with GitHub Actions or workflows to accomplish the same objective?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to implement this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to allow users to trigger pipe only for some single commits, you could try to use a tag (or tags) to mark such commits, and then remove these tags by the same pipe. Or you could incorporate a branch naming convention and run pipe for branches with the specified prefix.

Comment: I can advise approach where developers add certain comment on `GitHub` PR which will trigger build, test or some other action. It can be accomplish with [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-pr-comment-build/) plugin. With such solution developers can do everything from `GitHub` and go to `Jenkins` only when something is not passing to check error message (or you can also add error message as comment to PR).